# How to restart Apache from Java application?

Tags: java, apache

I want to restart Apache from Java. I have tried using the following code to restart it.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c \"C:\\Program Files\\Apache\\Apache22\\bin\\httpd.exe\" -k restart -n \"localServer\"");
```

This doesn't seem to work from inside a Java program (it does work if i put it into the command line). I know I'm eventually going to run into issues with administrator stuff, but for now I just want to get it to restart the server. Can anyone give me any pointers?

I managed to figure this out and make it work with windows 7 and with the UAC admin thing.

```
Process stop = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"C:\\Program Files\\Apache\\Apache22\\bin\\elevate.exe\" -c \"C:\\Program Files\\Apache\\Apache22\\bin\\httpd.exe\" -k stop -n \"localServer\"");
```

there is then a second to start it again. The first call is to elevate which was a .exe i downloaded that elevated privileged so i was able to actually run the commands and the second then did the stop.

Comment: httpd.exe itself is a process, need not pass it to cmd.

Comment: does it make much of a difference? the code still wont run from inside a java appliction ive tried many variations of the line of code

Comment: moreover, possibility is, u wont be able to run it on vista to later version of windows, because of file-permission. So if you know to grant all the permission to **current user** or move apache server out of **program files**.